Accessing docker containered services from my not containered spring web API
I have a project it has four services and one API; I use spring web. I have to docker container my services but I can't docker container my API. There are users and when they log in they get jwt. A logged in user needs to access dockered services from the API but someone who did not login from API (so they don't have a jwt) can't access them. I can't find a way to do that. Can anyone help?
I couldn't think anyway to link a API to dockered services.

Please don't re-ask the same question.  Edit your original question to add more details about what you're doing and what problems you're running into.
